# Eclipse Juno crashes frequently, no logs

Tags: eclipse, log, crash

I downloaded Eclipse Juno CDT and am using it with Kubuntu 14.04 . Unfortunately, it keeps crashing on every other action I take... for example, if I try to load the Editor options - crash. I can't see a relevant log file, and there are no relevant entries in the Error Log View the UI gives you.

Why could this be happenning? What can I do about it?